# How to retrieve only part of a document back in a call

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I need to retrieve only part of a document and call it via a helper so that I can render a subtemplate multiple times as the part I require to pull from the db is an array of object itself.  I have the following as the fields.  What I need to do with my helper is only retrieve the `ordersDispatch` array of one particular document which would be uniquely called by the `tripNumber` field.

I have tried several things but nothing has come close to only having an array of the objects in the orderDisptach field be returned in a fashion that it can be used by the helper to render my subtemplate for each object in the array.

```
{
                tripNumber:                 companyRecord.lastTripNum + 1,
                custID:                     $('input:hidden[name=orderCustomerId]').val(),
                custContact:                $('input:text[name=customerContact]').val(),
                custEmail:                  $('input:text[name=customerEmail]').val(),
                trailerSealNum:             $('input:text[name=trailerSealNum]').val(),
                orderBroker:                $('input:text[name=orderBroker]').val(),
                orderEquipment:             $('input:text[name=orderEquipment]').val(),
                orderLoadNum:               $('input:text[name=orderLoadNum]').val(),
                orderPlacedDate:            $('input:text[name=orderPlacedDate]').val(),
                orderPrivateNotes:          $('textarea[name=orderPrivateNotes]').val(),
                orderPublicNotes:           $('textarea[name=orderPublicNotes]').val(),


                orderCurrency:              $("input[name=orderCurrency]:checked").val(),
                orderCharges:               $('input:text[name=orderCharges]').val(),

                orderFUELCheck:             $('input:checkbox[name=orderFUELCheck]').is(':checked'),
                orderFUELPerc:              $('input:text[name=orderFUELPerc]').val(),
                orderFUELTotal:             $('input:text[name=orderFUELTotal]').val(),

                orderGSTCheck:              $('input:checkbox[name=orderGSTCheck]').is(':checked'),
                orderGSTPerc:               $('input:text[name=orderGSTPerc]').val(),
                orderGSTTotal:              $('input:text[name=orderGSTTotal]').val(),

                orderPSTCheck:              $('input:checkbox[name=orderPSTCheck]').is(':checked'),
                orderPSTPerc:               $('input:text[name=orderPSTPerc]').val(),
                orderPSTTotal:              $('input:text[name=orderPSTTotal]').val(),

                orderTAXCheck:              $('input:checkbox[name=orderTAXCheck]').is(':checked'),
                orderTAXPerc:               $('input:text[name=orderTAXPerc]').val(),
                orderTAXTotal:              $('input:text[name=orderTAXTotal]').val(),

                orderTotalCharges:          $('input:text[name=orderTotalCharges]').val(),

                ordeBlockInvoicing:         $('input:checkbox[name=ordeBlockInvoicing]').is(':checked'),

                orderExtraCharges:          orderExtraCharges,
                orderPickups:               puLocations,
                orderDeliveries:            delLocations,
                orderDispatch:              dispatchLocations,

                createdDate: new Date(),
                createdUser: currentUser.username
```

Any help in building a helper that will accomplish this would be greatly appreciated as I am new to meteor and mongo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following helper should give you what you need:

```
Template.oneTrip.helpers({
  orderDispatch: function(tn){
    return Trips.findOne({ tripNumber: tn }).orderDispatch;
  }
});
```

`Trips.findOne({ tripNumber: tn })` gets you an individual document and `.orderDispatch` returns the value of the `orderDispatch` key which in your case will be an array.

html:

```
<template name="oneTrip">
  {{#each orderDispatch this._id}} <!-- assuming you've already set the data context to an individual order -->
    {{this}} <!-- now the data context is an element of the orderDispatch array -->
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Comment: Took me a bit but I was able to get this method to work.  I had two problems, one the code I had to call up the orderDisptach was wrong and second I was using a ReactiveArray to hold my data before the insert and did a straight assign in the insert command.  This ended up makeing orderDispatch an object that contained objects instead of the desired array of objects.  Once I fixed that this worked like a charm.